# JavaFX how to set the text of a label in the calling controller, from the called controller

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, netbeans-8

I'm a JavaFX (and Java) newbie and a newbie StackOverflow user, too, so my apologies in advance if I get things wrong!

I'm trying to create an app that has a main scene that loads several different scenes as panes.  Each of the different scenes is loaded by a button on the main scene (rather like a tabbed pane).

I have a label on the main screen for displaying error messages.  I would like the scenes to update the main scene's label text as errors are encountered but am struggling with knowing how to do that.  I've Googled and tried dozens of suggestions to no avail.  Would someone be able to show me what I'm doing wrong please?  Many thanks!

I've created a test app that shows what I'm trying to do.  I'm using JavaSE8 and NetBeans8.2.

Main app:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

FXMLMain.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testapp.FXMLMainController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorView" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btnLoadView1" layoutX="476.0" layoutY="39.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadView1" text="Load view 1" />
      <Label fx:id="lblSystemMessage" layoutX="411.0" layoutY="145.0" text="label for system messages" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLMainController.java

```
public class FXMLMainController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorMain;
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorView;
@FXML
private Button btnLoadView1;
@FXML
private Label lblSystemMessage;

Pane paneView1;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //Load View 1
    try {
        paneView1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLView1.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLMainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    anchorMain.getChildren().add(paneView1);
    paneView1.setVisible(false);

    //Load Views 2, 3, 4 et al.

}    

@FXML
private void loadView1(ActionEvent event) {

    paneView1.setVisible(true);

}


public void setSystemMessage (String text) {

    System.out.println("received text " + text);        
    lblSystemMessage.setText(text);
    System.out.println("lblSystemMessage.getText() is " + lblSystemMessage.getText());

}

}
```

FXMLView1.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorView1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testapp.FXMLView1Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="64.0" layoutY="45.0" text="This is view 1" />
      <Button fx:id="btnView1SimulateError" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#view1SimulateError" text="Simulate error" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLView1Controller.java

```
public class FXMLView1Controller implements Initializable {


@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorView1;
@FXML
private Button btnView1SimulateError;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

@FXML
private void view1SimulateError(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println("simulating error from View 1");

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root = loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLView1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    FXMLMainController mainController = loader.getController();    
    mainController.setSystemMessage("FRED");        

}


}
```

When I run the app and click on btnLoadView1 and then click on btnView1SimulateError, I get the following output from the setSystemMessage method in FXMLMainController:

```
simulating error from View 1
received text FRED
lblSystemMessage.getText() is FRED
```

but the label text in the main scene isn't updated to "FRED".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to call the `setSystemMessage()` function of **FXMLMainController** from **FXMLView1Controller**. The problem is that to do so, you would need to have a refernce to the main controller. So, you need to provide one.

This is one of the possible solutions. You load your FXMLView1.fxml from the `initialize` function of the main controller. So, you can get the controller, allocated in the load. Here is an example:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLView1.fxml"));
    try {
        paneView1 = loader.load();
        FXMLView1Controller view1Controller = loader.getController();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         ...
    }
```

Now you have you view1Controller. You can do whatever you want to it. I suggest that you add a **mainController** field to it and do

```
 view1Controller.mainController = this;
```

and later when you need,

```
 mainController.setSystemMessage(message);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly.  I understood all but this line:  "view1Controller.mainController = this;".  What does that actually do?  When I added it, NetBeans added "FXMLMainController mainController;" in the FXMLView1Controller code.  When I println, I can see it's set to "testapp.FXMLMainController@2a13b30e".  How is it that I can access the mainController variable from the FXMLMainController code?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, the penny just dropped - now that I have a reference to the View1 Controller, I can set one of it's variables.  And having set it to "this", the View 1 Controller now has a reference back to the Main Controller.  I get it now.  Lovely solution.  Thanks!